# Are Python 3.11 objects as light as slots?

Tags: python, python-internals, slots, python-3.11

After [Mark Shannon's optimisation of Python objects](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89503), is a plain object different from an object with slots?
I understand that after this optimisation in a normal use case, objects [have no dictionary](https://github.com/faster-cpython/ideas/issues/72).
Have the new Python objects made the use of slots totally unnecessary?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, `__slots__` still produces more compact objects.

With `__slots__` for attributes, an object's memory layout only needs one pointer per slot. With the new lazy `__dict__` creation, an object needs to store a `PyDictValues` object and a pointer to that `PyDictValues` object.

The [`PyDictValues` object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Include/internal/pycore_dict.h#L131-L136) contains room for a number of pointers based on the ["usable size"](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Objects/dictobject.c#L5359) of the shared keys object when the `PyDictValues` object is created, which is usually more pointers than what you would have gotten with `__slots__`. It also holds some extra metadata and padding, stored before those pointers: a "prefix size" representing the size of this metadata, a "used size" representing the number of values stored, and an array of bytes tracking insertion order. The [padding](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Objects/dictobject.c#L696) is used to ensure this extra metadata doesn't interfere with the alignment of the pointers. (None of this is reflected in the `PyDictValues` struct definition, since C struct definitions aren't expressive enough for this - it mostly has to be handled manually.)

So, without `__slots__`, you've got an extra `PyDictValues *` in the object directly, usually more room allocated for attribute pointers than necessary, and a bunch of extra metadata in the `PyDictValues` itself, relative to using `__slots__`.

Plus, with `__slots__`, if you don't explicitly declare a `__weakref__` slot, you don't get one, saving some memory at the cost of not being able to create weak references to your objects. With no `__slots__`, Python will automatically add a `__weakref__` slot to your objects.